# Expression « se faire licencier »

Tags: constructions, auxiliaires

On entend souvent les gens dire :

> je me suis fait licencier.

Cependant, cette phrase exprime une certaine volonté comme pour :

> Je me suis fait couper les cheveux

La formule est-elle correcte, la personne ayant subi son licenciement et ne l'ayant en aucun cas demandé ?

C'est la même chose pour :

> se faire tirer dessus, se faire agresser…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*se faire + verbe à l'infinitif* n'exprime pas de volonté mais s'utilise pour une action que l'on subit (qu'elle soit voulue ou pas ne change rien). C'est une construction passive (ce n'est pas le sujet qui agit) qui met généralement l'accent sur une personne (contrairement à *mes cheveux ont été coupés* qui met l'accent sur un objet).

Comment: merci pour la remarque, l'utilisation de "on" comme sujet est en effet une autre construction possible de la même phrase. Cependant, le verbe est alors conjugué sous sa forme active: On m'a coupé les cheveux (passé composé). L'infinitif ne s'utilise pas dans ce cas de figure.

Comment: J'ai effacé ma remarque qui contenait une grosse bétise signalée par @radouxju, et je reformule : "je me suis fait + verbe à l'infinitif" peut également se dire "on m'a + participe passé du verbe".